# how to check if stylus was installed in mac?

Tags: stylus

I typed:

```
  npm install stylus
```

and I got this output:

```
 stylus@0.50.0 node_modules/stylus
 ├── css-parse@1.7.0
 ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
 ├── debug@2.1.1 (ms@0.6.2)
 ├── sax@0.5.8
 ├── source-map@0.1.43 (amdefine@0.1.0)
 └── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
```

but when i type

```
  stylus stylus/main.styl --out /css --compress
```

or

```
  stylus
```

I get this output:

```
  -bash: stylus: command not found
```

can you please help me with this? I want to compile stylus files to .css files in a laravel project.

Answer (score 3):

You installed it locally (to `node_modules` folder of the current dir). To install it globally, run:

```
npm install stylus -g
```